# Deciphering word related to Farrier occupation in 1881 Census?

Tags: england, census-records, palaeography, 1880s

I have a word under the job description title of my ancestor that I can't understand. The top line:

```
Farrier  (unknown word)  Smith
then follows:
Farriers Wife
Farrierboy
Farriers Daughter
ditto
Scholar
ditto
```

My ancestor is otherwise known as a Farrier, Wheelwright and Smith in other documents. The last letters are suspected to be 'eral'. The second looks to be an 'f' the first possibly even an 'a'. But even with these possibilities I cannot get it to make sense.

It is from a census record in 1881.

[image: Farrier ? Smith]

Answer (score 5):

I think the words, and thus the recorded occupation of your ancestor, are:

> Farrier & General Smith